What is the maximum bonus to profession rolls that can be achieved in Pathfinder at level 20 with one level in Asmodean Advocate Cleric?
I have been working on a Asmodean Advocate Cleric and as their primary features lets them sub the Profession(Barister) in place of Diplomacy and bluff. As such I was looking into ways that can be used to boost her profession skill but I haven't had much luck finding anything that would give me direction as there does not appear to be any guides on how to maximize profession rolls. So to reiterate the question, what is the highest bonus that a character can have to profession rolls assuming they have at least one level as an Asmodean Advocate cleric?

Is this at least 1 level or exactly/about 1 level? Because "The Asmodean advocate gains an insight bonus equal to 1/2 her cleric level (minimum +1) on... all Profession (barrister) checks." is one of the potential boosts.

Bonuses specific to Profession:

Asmodean Advocate (Cleric) +1/2 level insight
Master Craftsman (Feat) +2 untyped
Breadth of Experience (Feat, Dwarf, elf, or gnome; 100+ years old) +2 untyped
Taldor Noble Scion, Talbot (Feat) +2 untyped (and can use as Knowledge 1/day)
Prodigy (Feat) +2, +4 at 10+ ranks untyped
Trade Talk (Trait) +1 trait
Simple Disciple (Trait) +1 trait

To summarize, your best option is to take either Trait, be either a Talbot or old Dwarf/Elf/Gnome, and level to 20 as a Cleric* taking the Prodigy and Master Craftsman feats. Your bonus should be:

20 ranks +3 Class Skill +9(ish) Wisdom +10 Insight +1 Trait +8 untyped
= +51

This number might be further boosted by generic skill boosts.
*You can dip three levels into Investigator to trade +2 bonus for +1d6 (INT)+1/day. That does not seem like a worthy trade-off, to me.
Honorable mentions:

Esquire attache case +2 circumstance (specific uses of Profession(barrister))
Signature Skill (Feat) - Unlocks the Unchained Skill Unlock effects
Knight of Coins (Paladin, level 3) +4 sacred
Expanded Inspiration (Investigator) +1d6 untyped (INT+1/2 level times per day)

Amazing Inspiration (level 7) +1d8 untyped




Genius Avaricious (spell) is expensive and unwise, but another +5 untyped if you pay someone; Patient Calm (trait) allows you to take 12, but Bluff checks don't generally work well with taking 10; the esquire attache case looks like a specific version of the masterwork tool rules, and Masterwork Transformation (spell) should let you make a custom version; and Master of Ledgers (feat) is another untyped +2 with some other goodies.

@Phoenices I've converted the answer to a community wiki; there seems to be too much content for one person to answer 'every bonus to X', so you can add in your pieces (or I can do it when I have more time). Good catches.

note that you will also get a +3 for it being a class skill and +6 if you take Skill Focus.

I knew I was forgetting something (the +3). I didn't go looking for every skill bonus (but people can edit those in if they like)
